# Rewrite and beautiful viariables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have links like `domain.com/MyFile.php?var1=data&var2=test` and I want to rewrite the links to this form: `domain.com/MyFile.php/data/test`

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^MyFile.php/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /MyFile.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
```

This doesn't work (don't send variables). This works:

```
RewriteRule ^MyFile/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /MyFile.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
```

But I would like the link to have a file extension.

Comment: Do u have any other rules?

Comment: Yes but this same for other files

Comment: Could you explain in few words whats not working?

Comment: This rules don't forward variables. But I have this problem on one server.

Comment: Do you have url rewriting permission on this server?(htaccess=enabled|disabled)